# Who was the king who argued with Adi Shankaracharya using karma siddantha (law of karma)?

Tags: history, philosophy, adi-shankaracharya

What is the name of the king who debated with Adi Shankaracharya against Advaita and supporting karma siddhantha (law of karma)?

Which authentic text contains the discussion between them?

Comment: Do you think Advaita refutes law of karma?

Comment: No, but the king is a strict follower of the law of karma and didn't agree on Advaita quickly. @Chinmay Sarupria

Comment: @hanugm Do you know the details of the king already? You said that he didn't agree immediately. Where have you heard this story? It was Mandana Mishra belonging to Purvamimamsa who emphasized on Karma. He was not a king.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma  No, from discussions I came to know these but did not study mydelf till....